# How can I assign class object into a class

Tags: c++

I need to creat an object Pokemon in the main()

that assign it into the class PokemonWorld, and let the PokemonWolrd to decide which PokemonStation is this Pokemon need to go

I tired get the data separatly (get name and hp) and get together(get a Pokemon class)

but both fail

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;



class Pokemon {
public:
    Pokemon() {};

    Pokemon(char x[], int n) {
        strncpy_s(name, x, 10);
        hp = n;
    };
private:
    char name[10];
    int hp;
};

class PokemonStation {
private:
    Pokemon **list= new Pokemon*[1000];
public:
    PokemonStation() {};
    PokemonStation(int x) {
        id = x;
    };
    int id;
    void assigntoList(int i,Pokemon x)
    { 
        if (i > 0)
            i--;
        list[i] = new Pokemon(x);
        cout << "creat" << list[i];
    };
};

class PokemonWorld {
private:
    char name[10];
public:
    PokemonStation s1;
    PokemonStation s2;
    PokemonWorld() {};
    PokemonWorld(char x[], int y=1, int z=2) {
        strncpy_s(name, x, 10);
        PokemonStation s1(y);
        PokemonStation s2(z);

    };
    const char* const getName() const{
        return name;
    };
    void assigntoStation(int i,Pokemon x) {
        if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
            s1.assigntoList(i, x);
        else
            s2.assigntoList(i, x);
    };
};

void main() {
    int number,hp,i;
    char name[10];
    cout << "What is the World Name ?" <<endl;
    cin >> name;

    PokemonWorld world(name);

    cout << "Please input the number of Pokemon in the " << world.getName() <<" world:" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    Pokemon **mon = new Pokemon*[number];
    cout << "Please input the characteristics of all Pokemon: Name HP" << endl;
    for (i = 0;i < number;i++)
    {
        cin >> name >> hp;
        mon[i] = new Pokemon(name, hp);
        world.assigntoStation(i,*(mon[i]));
    }
    for (i = 0;i < number;i++)

    cout << "world is " << world.getName() << endl;


    system("pause");

};
```

Comment: If you want a dynamic list of things in C++, you should use an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of a raw array. Also use [`std::string`s](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) for text.

Comment: What exactly in your program isn't working?

Comment: when I try to print out the pokemon in the function assigntoList in class PokemonStation to test did I successfully assign the Pokemon into the list[i], it print out the address of list [i]

Comment: put clear question

Comment: @Adib the question is How can I assign class object into a class

Comment: Hey tried to understand your program but couldn't but i think in general
What you can try to do is inheritance rather than calling a class object in another class Inheritance is very useful tool in object oriented programming. You can check out this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you should use [`std::vector`s](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) for dynamic lists of things and [`std::string`s](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) for text. If you know Java, these are like `ArrayList` and `String`. (To use these, make sure you `#include` `<vector>` and `<string>`.)

For instance, your `Pokemon` class, rewritten with `name` as a `string`:

```
class Pokemon {
public:
    Pokemon() {}

    Pokemon(string name, int hp):name(name), hp(hp) { // construct the fields directly

    }
private:
    string name;
    int hp;
};
```

And your `PokemonStation` class, rewritten using a `vector` for the list of Pokemon:

```
class PokemonStation {
private:
    vector<Pokemon> list;
public:
    PokemonStation() {}
    PokemonStation(int x):id(x) {}
    int id;
    void assignToList(Pokemon x)
    { 
        list.push_back(x); // add x to the list
    }
};
```

If you want to print a `Pokemon` with `cout <<`, then you'll have to overload the `<<` operator to define what gets printed. Add this into your class:

```
class Pokemon {
public:
    ...
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Pokemon& p) {
        out << p.name; // just print the name
        return out;
    }
    ...
};
```

Just make sure that you're `cout`ing a `Pokemon`, not a pointer-to-`Pokemon` (`Pokemon*`), and you won't get an address.